# Oracle data transfer to Postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

Does anyone know an efficient method of transferring data to a Postgres database from an Oracle 11 database.

I need to regularly insert data into a table on the Postgres side or possibly write data using an Oracle Queue if this is not possible.

Comment: Google 'oracle postgresql bridge" and you'll get several hits on how to do this.

Comment: Use a foreign table

Comment: The question lacks detail of what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on foreign table? Can this be achieved using Oracle queue?

Comment: We need to transfer data regularly from Oracle to Postgres in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

I used ora2pg https://ora2pg.darold.net/documentation.html for Oracle->PostgreSQL schema and data migration.

Database like 50GB. It took several minutes.

I transferred data once. But ora2pg tool is highly customizable. I am sure you can use subquery in it.

If subquery is not possible you can create a view on Oracle's side showing only data to be transferred. And migrate from the view.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at this but management is against installing any tools. Forgot to mention our Oracle is running on OpenVMS.

Comment: Operating system does not matter. You can install ora2pg on third machine. Separate from Oracle and PostgreSQL.